# Deselecting NSTableView when clicked somewhere outside the table

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview

I have a NSTableView placed on top of NSView. I want to deselect the NSTableView when mouse pointer is clicked on NSView. How to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean “on top of”? You shouldn't normally put one view on top of one of its siblings in the view hierarchy; you should only put views *inside* other views. In other words, two views that are siblings should not overlap; you should make one a subview of the other.

Comment: Thats correct. One is a subview of the other. But how do I achieve the functionality of delesecting the table?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “deselect the table view”? Revoke its first-responder status, or deselect any selected rows in it?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but one option is to subclass NSTableView and override its mouseDown:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {

    [super mouseDown:event];

    NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:point];

    if (row == -1) { // We didn't click any row

        [self deselectAll:nil];
    }
}
```

Swift 3 version:

```
override open func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(with: event)

    let point    = convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
    let rowIndex = row(at: point)

    if rowIndex < 0 { // We didn't click any row
        deselectAll(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it is unadvisable to call the superclass to handle the mouseDown: event, since you seem to handle the event yourself completely.

Comment: @Fnord23 No, super still needs to deal with selection of rows on `mouseDown`, this one only deals with deselection.